# Creating variable on heap and return the same variable

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Hi i have few doubt related to heap variable...

I want to write a function as below ->

```
struct test
{
   int x;
   int y;
};

test* fun()
{
    test *ptr = new test;

    return ptr;
}
```

1. My doubt is returning a heap variable once it will go out of scope it will lost its value.
2. There is definitely a memory leak.(As heap variable is not deleted.)

So how can i design such kind of function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamically allocated objects (what you call heap variables) do not get destroyed at the end of the scope in which they were created. That's the whole point of dynamic allocation. While the `test` object is dynamically allocated, the pointer `ptr` is not - it *will* be destroyed when it goes out of scope. But that's okay! You copy the value of the pointer out of the function and this copy still points at the `test` object. The `test` object is still there. The function you've written is fine, but it isn't exactly good style.

Yes, there is a memory leak if nobody ever does `delete` on a pointer to the `test` object you created. That's a problem with returning raw pointers like this. You have to trust the caller to `delete` the object you're creating:

```
void caller()
{
  test* p = fun();
  // Caller must remember to do this:
  delete p;
}
```

A common C-style way of doing this (which is definitely not recommended in C++) is to have a `create_test` and `destroy_test` pair of functions. This still puts the same responsibility on the caller:

```
void caller()
{
  test* p = create_test();
  // Caller must remember to do this:
  destroy_test(p);
}
```

The best way to get around this is to not use dynamic allocation. Just create a `test` object on the stack and copy it (or move it) out of the function:

```
test fun()
{
    test t;
    return t;
}
```

If you *need* dynamic allocation, then you should use a smart pointer. Specifically, the `unique_ptr` type is what you want here:

```
std::unique_ptr<test> fun()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<test>(new test());
}
```

The calling function can then handle the `unique_ptr` without having to worry about doing `delete` on it. When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, it will automatically `delete` the `test` object you created. The caller can however pass it elsewhere if it wants some other function to have the object.

Comment: but some times we need to create pointer ...and with out using a smart pointer is there any way of improvement?

Comment: If you need dynamic allocation and you can't use smart pointers, then you have to pass raw pointers around like you are doing. That's not very good C++ style, however.

Comment: @Badshah No, your function works as it is. It just relies on the caller doing something that you can't be sure they will.

Comment: adding: and in current implementaion how caller can take care as you have mentioned that "caller to delete"

Comment: @Badshah I added an example. You can't enforce that the caller does anything. That's why you use smart pointers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23451/discussion-between-badshah-and-sftrabbit)

Answer (score 2):

1. You are not returning a heap variable, you are returning a value of a stack variable that holds a pointer to the heap. The stack variable goes out of scope; the memory pointed to by the pointer is in the heap - it never goes out of scope.
2. There will be a memory leak unless you release the memory in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is [that] returning a heap variable once it will go out of scope it will lo[se] its value.

No worry, because since you're returing the pointer by *value*; so the pointer will go out of scope, but since you're returning the memory that it points to, there is no memory leak (only if we can rely on the caller to delete it).

However, if we had returned the pointer by *reference* then we would have a problem:

```
test*& fun() // note the & (reference)
{
    test *ptr = new test;

    return ptr;
}
```

Here you're returning a reference to a temporary. When the variable goes out of scope you will be using an object that doesn't exist. This is why you can't return temporaries by reference.

Answer (score 0):

> > My doubt is returning a heap variable once it will go out of scope it will lost its value.

No heap variable does not go out of scope as do go stack variables...

> > There is definitely a memory leak.(As heap variable is not deleted.)

Yes we have to free memory allocated on heap by ourself, otherwise there is memory leak...

I would suggest to read [some tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/dynamic_memory_allocation.html) related to it.